# Prove that $\prod_{k=1}^n (1+ \frac nk(e^{-i/n} -1))(1+ i/k)$ converges towards $\prod_{k=1}^\infty (1+1/k^2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, infinite-product

I look for an elegant proof that $$\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+ \frac nk(e^{-i/n} -1)\right)\left(1+ \frac{i}k\right)$$ converges towards $\displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$.

Here, $i^2 = -1$.

Answer (score 0):

*Elegant*, not sure at all !

Let
$$a_k= \Big[1+\frac{
   n}{k}\left(e^{-\frac{i}{n}}-1\right)\Big]\left(1+\frac{i}{k}\right)$$ and you look for
$$P_n=\prod_{k=1}^n a_k  $$
When $n$ is large, using
$$e^{-\frac{i}{n}}=1-\frac{i}{n}-\frac{1}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ which makes
$$a_k =\left(1+\frac{1}{k^2}\right)-\frac{k+i}{2 k^2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Comment: $a_k$ should be $a_{k,n}$ I believe and the big $O$ uniform in $k$. I am fine with that. How do you conclude?